# Java, create runnable jar file including ONLY used dependencies.

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

This question has been asked before, but have no satisfactory answer yet!

I have a Java Main.java class in a project full of other unrelated classes. I would like to export that Main.java into an executable jar file, containing only the dependencies it ACTUALLY uses.

Is this possible, if so how?

Both Eclipse( create runnable jar ) and Intellij ( create artifact ) will include all dependencies defined in the module containing the Main.java class.

Comment: If you are using dynamic instantiation, I don't think there is any chance of determining the dependency tree without solving the halting problem first.

Comment: Why would you have dependencies in the Java Build Path that you aren't using? What answers have you gotten so far?

Comment: Just add only the dependencies you need to the build path. Either that or manually specify them in the mainfest

Comment: @nitind Because it is very convient. I don't need to create a new project and pull in various dependencies for every static void main I create, do I? It would be crazy to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using a dependency management system, instead of the ones provided by default in Eclipse and IDEA. Many Java developers (including me) use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). If you're working in Eclipse, it includes [m2eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)

You don't want to have all the dependencies in one project because it can get really bloated. However, if you have a Maven parent `pom` that uses the `<dependencyManagement>` tag, you can easily just reference this parent `pom` and then easily only make references to the dependencies you need in that sub project. This keeps everything separate that actually is separate, and provides an easy organization mechanism - the reason why people use Maven.

[How to use `<dependencyManagement>` in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Maven also has plugins that manage your jar creation for you, e.g. `maven-assembly-plugin` that allow you to construct your dependencies exactly how you want them in the jar and so forth.

---

You have to do this yourself somehow. What do you expect any IDE / dependency management system to do with the following code:

Test.java

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String... args) {
         System.exit(0);
         new Foo(null);
     }
}
```

Foo.java

```
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;

public class Foo {
    public Foo(String s) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(s);
    }
}
```

The Guava dependency is not needed here... but you only know that in RUNTIME. If you include all the import statements of all the classes, then you include all the dependencies. If you don't, then you need to do runtime analysis. Your problem is akin to the [Turing halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Yeah, not good enough. I will be extracting the jar and removing all dependencies manually. ( Can't believe Java hasn't gotten further than this )

Comment: @SecretService How is that better than making the configuration file do what you want?

Comment: You said: "You don't want to have all the depencies in a one project ... " that's exactly what I want. I have no interest in creating a maven module for each static void main I create. I just want to extract the classes I use.

Comment: @SecretService How will your code know what classes you use? Maven makes this task easier and faster, but not completely automatic, because that's next to impossible.

Comment: that is a silly example because whatever the class needs to import should be pulled in, otherwise it wouldn't compile. I am not talking about runtime analyzation, but purely statical one, things that can be detected during compile time.

Comment: @SecretService You are talking about runtime analysis. See the modified example that shows why.

Comment: So you are saying that if I remove the import statement from Foo, then javac would be ok with that?

Comment: @SecretService I'm saying that your runnable jar isn't dependent on Guava, but it would be very difficult to figure that out at compile time. The code that instantiates `Foo` never runs.